# How to keep in Analytics Cloud data that have been deleted in Salesforce ?

Tags: data, einstein-analytics, analytics

I’m trying to figure out how to keep the data of my Leads records in Analytics even though they have been deleted from the Lead object in the Salesforce environment. I’ve ran into the “IsDeleted” field while creating and manipulating Dataflow, Datasets and replication mode. I definitely need to dig deeper into this but I’ve also read things about querying “allrows” using SAQL. I’m not confident yet enough with SAQL so any help or recommendations would be highly appreciated on this topic!

Is it possible to prevent Analytics from deleting records while using replication with incremental mode active? I definitely need the data to be update and insert, but I’d like to get rid of the delete feature. I need to keep the data in Analytics even though it has been permanently deleted from the recycle bin.

Cheers guys and have a great week-end!
Gildas